# Pairs of values and sort using the first one java

Tags: java, sorting

I have a big file with pairs of values and I want to sort them based on the first value. For example

```
  1,2
  3,4
  1,3
  5,2
  1,5
```

And I want to sort them based on the first value.How will I do that?

Comment: Read the file, parse the first number on each line and compare all of them to do the sort.

Comment: It's huge file 30 gb.It's efficient?

Comment: Efficiency depends on how you write your code. I only gave you guidelines, since there is no code or real attempt at solving your issue. The idea is that you read the file, parse the first number on each line and use it to perform the custom sort. Code it, and if you get stuck or need some hint come back here with a specific question.

Comment: So , i will read the first value and compare it with all the first value of each line and write it to another file?

Comment: Yes, this is the idea.

Comment: If data doesn't fit into your memory you may consider what is called **external sorting** ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting)). The technique is simple, split the data into parts which are readable and sort them, repeat and in the end merge everything sorted together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you've done all the boilerplate code for reading the file and storing it into some type of collection. you can then sort your collection based on the first value of each string.

```
TreeSet<String> resultSet = myCollection.parallelStream().sorted(
            Comparator.comparingInt((String e) -> Integer.parseInt(e.substring(0,e.indexOf(",")))))
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new));
```

*note* - ensure you've trimmed all the whitespace from each string when reading the file before accumulating it into your temporary collection or  if you want, you can trim it before the `e.substring` call i.e `e.trim().substring(0,e.indexOf(",")))`.

**edit**

The above solution assumes that each string within `myCollection` could have more than 1 digit before or after the delimiter `,`. However, assuming there will always be 1 digit before and after the `,` delimiter you need not sort any data rather use a `TreeSet` as the accumulator collection when reading the file instead of a `HashSet` because it will sort the data as you're adding string objects to the collection.

Comment: If the number is always 1 digit long, you can also do: `Comparator.comparingInt((String e) -> e.charAt(0) - '0')`

Comment: It's not 1 digits it's 3 digits. I have used HashSet<String> because is O(1) ,  then add "1,2" , "1,3" , "4,1".Like that, it will work with HashSet?

Comment: @Aominè `HashSet` doesn't maintain insertion order, resultSet would not be an ordered one, also the file size is huge 30G, external sort might do.

Comment: @Saravana completely forgotten about that. thanks for pointing it out. See edit.

Comment: @Aominè `TreeSet` is **suboptimal** if the input already comes sorted. You may want to consider using `LinkedHashSet` instead. Alternatively drop the `Stream#sorted` call and just collect into `TreeSet`, it sorts automatically.

Comment: @Zabuza sorry maybe I'm missing something here? alright sure that taking all the data from the `HashSet` which OP is currently using as an accumulator for the data within the file and dumping it into a `TreeSet` would sort the data _but_ this is only assuming each string within the source collection is made of 2 individual digits separated by a `,` any other case where a string is made of more than 1 digit separated by a `,` would not sort properly as it's represented as a string. nevertheless, i'll edit to include the scenario in which there's only 2 digits separated by a `,`.

Comment: @Aominè you may need to use `List` or `LinkedHashSet`, though you sort the elements while adding them to `TreeSet` it will be again sorted with natural order using its implicit String `Comparator`, so the insertion order is not guaranteed again.

Comment: @Aominè also in this use case we no need to sort by a custom `Comparator` since its a string of numbers, natural ordering of string will sort it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i don't know much, but i suggest a while/for loop that reads each pair (num1, num2) and `if (num1>num2){num1 now has the value of num2, and vice versa}`. This would order the pairs. Now, I suggest another for/while loop that goes through the first number of each pair, and apllies a sorting algorithm such as:

```
for(int i = 0; i<= numberOfPairs; i++){
    int number = firstOfPair[i];
    for(int j = i; j<=(numberOfPairs-i; j++){
        if(firstOfPair[j] > number){
           auciliarVariable = firstOfPair[j];
           firstOfPair[j] = firstOfPair[i];
           firstOfPair[i] = auxiliarVariable;
         }
    }
}
```